Automatically highlight a row in green when a column value is above 0 in google sheet
For example, if I input a value of 1 into column A1, ONLY the entire FIRST ROW should be automatically highlighted into green. And, if I type -1 the FIRST row should be automatically highlighted into red.
How do I achieve this?
I tried conditioning formatting but it only highlights the column

For green, apply this conditional formatting custom formula rule to the range A1:Z:
=($A1 > 0) * isnumber($A1)

For red, open the green rule, click Add, replace the > in the rule with <, and change the color.
See Lance's explanation of how absolute and relative addresses work in a conditional formatting custom formula rule.
